# Setting CommandType to StoredPRocedure when invoking function

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, ado.net, user-defined-functions

when invoking an SQL functions by means of ADO.NET, is it allowed to set CommandType.StoredPRocedure? I know that the purpose of this enum is to specify a stored procedure; for functions CommandType.Text should be used. But I don't like writting some select statements (CommandText = "SELECT foo FROM dbo.Goo") in .NET code.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work. Basically you should :

- define a parameter with Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue to fetch the result
- call ExecuteNonScalar

See this post from GSerg for an example :

[ExecuteScalar always returns null when calling a scalar-valued function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932199/executescalar-always-returns-null-when-calling-a-scalar-valued-function/6932462#6932462)