# Specified cast is not valid when trying Convert.ToInt32(value)

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, exception

I am trying to run a stored procedure and for some reason it keeps telling me `"Specified cast is not valid"`. the "`hidSelectedExpenseIDs`" is a hidden field that gets populated with a javascript array of id's.

Example: the `"hidSelectedExpenseIDs.Value"` would look like "123,124,125,126". Hence why I have the `.Split(',')` in there.

Here is my code:

```
public void hasExhistingExpenseInvoice()
{
    string[] Expenses = hidSelectedExpenseIDs.Value.Split(',');

    //check if there is an existing invoice. Then report back to the user so the
    //user knows if he/she has to check overwrite option.
    bool invoiceExists = false;

    foreach (var expense in Expenses)
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OSCIDConnectionString"].ToString());
        var command = new SqlCommand("p_CaseFiles_Expenses_InvoiceExhists", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExpenseID", SqlDbType.Int));
        command.Parameters["@ExpenseID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(expense);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            invoiceExists = (bool)command.ExecuteScalar();
            if (invoiceExists)
            {
                //previous invoice exhists
                Warning1.Visible = true;
                Warning1.Text = "There is an exhisting Invoice.";
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException sql)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Couldn't connect to the Database - Error";
            lblStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)//catches exception here
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "An error occured";
            lblStatus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

this is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[InvoiceExhists]
@ExpenseID int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT InvNumber FROM dbo.Expenses from ExpID = @ExpenseID
END
```

Comment: Sounds like `hidSelectedExpenseIDs` doesn't always contain what you think it contains.  What's its value when this fails?

Comment: debug using a break point and see what value you get for variable expense

Comment: Are you sure that your `hidSelectedExpenseIDs.Value` doesn't have a ',' at the end?

Comment: when i ran it through the debugger, the value is "295" as a string hence the conversion. It just confuses me a little because I have it doing the same thing on other parts of my code and it works. It must be the (bool)cmd.ExecuteScalar() like  ramhound suggested

Comment: where do you get the exception .Is it on Convert.Toint32 or execute scalar

Comment: **Tip 1:** Don't create a connection inside a loop statement. You are oppening a connection for each iteration.  
**Tip 2:** Use `using` statements to dispose the connection and command objects.

Comment: if its on execute scalar alter your SQL Query to if exists

Comment: when it hits "invoiceExists = (bool) command.ExecuteScalar();...when reading now means I had it all wrong, it's not the Convert.toInt32 that is crashing , it's the bool conversion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic is faulty.

Your Query returns a number, and you are trying to cast it directly to a Boolean, this can't be done in C#.

Some languages will interpret any non-zero as true, it is not the case for C# and it will throw an exception.

You will need to compare the returned value.

In this case, you should just check if there is a value, because NULL will be returned if the invoice does not exist.

This would look like this :

```
invoiceExists = command.ExecuteScalar() != null ;
```

Also I recommend reading this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932199/executescalar-always-returns-null-when-calling-a-scalar-valued-function) and consider using UDF instead of scalar Stored Procedures.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I never knew you could do ExecuteScalar() != null;

Comment: This will evaluate and return a Boolean which will then be assigned to your invoiceExists variable.

Answer (score 2):

change your stored procedure .This fits your requirement

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InvoiceExhists]
@ExpenseID int
AS
BEGIN
if exists(select * Expenses where ExpID = @ExpenseID)
select 1
else
select 0
END
```

Comment: for some reason this code still returns a 1 even if there is no result

Comment: @john did you add the missing 'from' to the select

Answer (score 1):

The exception is likely caused by `invoiceExists = (bool)command.ExecuteScalar();` considering its the only casting that happens within the try statement.  You need to look at the return result of `ExecuteScalar()` to solve your problem.

Comment: when I run the query in my DB, it returns "InvNumber" as title then "12345" so it is returning a value

Comment: @john - Neither of those can be casted to a bool.  Infact they are both string values.