# Calling SQL Defined function in C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have written this scalar function in TSQL:

```
create function TCupom (@cupom int)
returns float
as
begin
    declare @Tcu float;

    select @Tcu = sum (total) from alteraca2 where pedido = @cupom 

    if (@tcu is  null)
        set @tcu = 0;

    return @tcu;
end
```

I want to call this function in my C# code. Here's what I have so far:

```
public void TotalCupom(int cupom)
{ 
    float SAIDA;           
    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();

    if (conex1.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    { 
        conex1.Open();
    }

    SqlCommand Totalf = new SqlCommand("Tcupom", conex1);
    SqlParameter code1 = new SqlParameter("@code", SqlDbType.Int);
    code1.Value = cupom ;
    Totalf.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure ;
    SAIDA = Totalf.ExecuteScalar();

    return SAIDA;
}
```

Comment: Are you having a problem? Would you like to tell us what it is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExecuteScalar always returns null when calling a scalar-valued function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932199/executescalar-always-returns-null-when-calling-a-scalar-valued-function)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can't just call the function name, you will need to write an inline SQL statement which makes use of the UDF:

```
SqlCommand Totalf = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.Tcupom(@code)", conex1);
```

And remove the `CommandType`, this isn't a Stored Procedure, its a User Defined Function.

In all:

```
public void TotalCupom(int cupom)
{ 
    float SAIDA;           
    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
    if (conex1.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        conex1.Open();
    }
    SqlCommand Totalf = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.Tcupom(@code)", conex1);
    SqlParameter code1 = new SqlParameter("@code", SqlDbType.Int);
    code1.Value = cupom;
    SAIDA = Totalf.ExecuteScalar();

    return SAIDA;
}
```

Comment: Actually because he did `Totalf.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` he can just call the function name.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Are you sure? What if there was a stored procedure called `Tcupom`? Surely SQL Server would get confused...

Comment: No, you are right, I just realized he was using a scalar function, not a table based function. I don't know if those can be called via SqlCommand set as StoredProcedure

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sorry you still haven't convinced me. This article refers to "Using Parameters with a SqlCommand and a Stored Procedure", it mentions nothing about User Defined Functions.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain To be honest I still don't understand how this would work with a table based UDF. I'd be interested to see some documentation.

Comment: number of corrections:
1. your method has a void return type and, you are returning something else (return SAIDA;)
2. you have initialize an SqlDataAdapter and it is never used.
3. ExecuteScalar(); returns an object, needs type conversion.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You were correct [originally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047057/calling-sql-defined-function-in-c-sharp#comment24645607_17047099). One can [call a scalar function with `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and without a wrapping `select`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932462/11683).

Comment: It needs many corrections and after all, its not working:
 SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();   never used?
 SqlParameter code1 = new SqlParameter("@code", SqlDbType.Int);  never used?

Comment: @MuniR the OP's code contains the unused `SqlDataAdapter` and the unused `SqlParameter` which means it could be utilized later on, or the OP could've removed it. I trust that it was left to the OP to figure out while the answerer focused purely on the setup for calling a UDF.

Answer (score 8):

```
...

try
{
    if (connectionState != ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "udfName";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        foreach (var cmdParam in sqlParams)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(cmdParam);
        }


        var retValParam = new SqlParameter("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int)
        {
            //Set this property as return value
            Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue 
        };

        cmd.Parameters.Add(retValParam);
        cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        retVal = retValParam.Value;
    }
}
finally
{
    if (connectionState == ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Close();
}

...
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. The function name ExecuteScalar is frustratingly misleading when calling SQL Scalar Functions instead of SQL Store Procedures. But the behaviour does match the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar)

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to call a SQL Function in the same way that I call Stored Procedures which is by using DeriveParameters and then setting the parameter values.  It turns out that this works with Scalar Functions out of the box and you can use ExecuteNonQuery and read the RETURN_VALUE.  Please see sample code below:

```
    public int GetLookupCodeFromShortCode(short tableType, string shortCode)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.fnGetLookupCodeFromShortCode", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 30;
                SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

                cmd.Parameters["@sintTableType"].Value = tableType;
                cmd.Parameters["@vchrShortCode"].Value = shortCode;
                cmd.Parameters["@chrLanguage"].Value = "en";
                cmd.Parameters["@chrCountry"].Value = "en";

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                return (int)cmd.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;
            }
        }

    }
```

The Scalar Function code looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetLookupCodeFromShortCode]( @sintTableType SMALLINT, @vchrShortCode VARCHAR(5), @chrLanguage CHAR(2), @chrCountry CHAR(2))

RETURNS INT

AS

BEGIN

    DECLARE @intLookupCode  INT

    SELECT @intLookupCode = LV.intLookupCode 
    FROM    
    tblLookupValueDesc LVD
        INNER JOIN tblLookupValue LV ON LV.sintLookupTableType = LVD.sintLookupTableType AND LV.intTableKey = LVD.intTableKey
    WHERE   
    LVD.sintLookupTableType = @sintTableType
    AND LVD.vchrShortCode = @vchrShortCode
    AND LVD.chrCountry = @chrCountry
    AND LVD.chrLanguage = @chrLanguage

    RETURN @intLookupCode 

END

GO
```

Comment: Where is @RETURN_VALUE coming from? Is it generated by DeriveParameters? I've been running this as-is with the exception of the DeriveParameter call and keep getting "An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@RETURN_VALUE' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection."