# how do i call a sql function from my asp.net project?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

This is my function:

```
create function fn_Inventory(@qty int, @item_ID int)  
returns int
as begin
    declare @result int

    set @result = (SELECT Quantity - @qty from Items where @item_ID = item_ID)
    return @result
end
```

And I want to execute this function from my asp.net code; how to do it?

Comment: like [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1612546.aspx?How+to+Call+SQL+function+from+ASP+net+application+)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047057/calling-sql-defined-function-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int TotalCupom(int qty,int item_ID)
    { 
        int result;           
        SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        if (conex1.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        { conex1.Open();}
        SqlCommand Totalf = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.fn_Inventory(@qty,@item_ID)", qty,item_ID);
        SqlParameter _qty= new SqlParameter("@qty", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter _item_ID= new SqlParameter("@item_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
        _qty.Value = qty;
        _item_ID.Value = item_ID;
        result= Totalf.ExecuteScalar();


        return result;
    }
```