# Configure Entity Framework 7 to run user defined SQL Server function

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Is it possible to map to DbContext user defined SQL Server function and use it as a standard method in C# code?

Let's say I have a db function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [IsNumberValid](
    @number INT
)
```

All logic for various reasons is in database.

Now I would like to have something like:

```
_dbContext.IsNumberValid(x)
```

Is it possible?

I found an article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping

but it does not work if method is executed outside of LINQ query so as I understand it is usefull when we need to add some logic to queries but I just want to use it as a standard method outside of linq query or even if in linq query then without any other DbSet. So **not** like it is described in the attached link:

```
var query2 = from p in context.Posts
select context.PercentageDifference(p.BlogId, 3);
```

So here that function: PercentageDifference is great but it is ecxecuted in filter for getting values from context.Posts, not as a "standalone" method.

Comment: Are you confusing UDFs with stored procedures? You can't call a UDF outside a query in SQL Server. EF Core can't change that

Comment: Ok so how can I call it as a query in c# but without writing SQL?

Comment: Just use EF Core power tools tomap the function for you

Comment: @ErikEJ what would be the output of it? Would it simply add something like return this.SqlQuery("SELECT IsNumberValid({number})") ? 
This is not because Im lazy, this is because I would like to avoid magic strings and sql in my code no matter if it is generated by tool or by me.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can't call UDFs outside queries at all. You'd have to use `SELECT IsNumberValid(..)`. In EF Core 7 you can call this query with `SqlQuery`.

You can hide this from the rest of the application code by adding a custom method to your DbContext :

```
public bool IsNumberValid(int number)
{
    return this.SqlQuery<int>($"SELECT IsNumberValid({number})")
               .FirstOrDefault() == 1;
}
```

Comment: `can't call UDFs outside queries at all` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932462/11683?

Comment: @GSerg *in T-SQL*? That link doesn't prove otherwise - you can't just call a scalar function by itself. What you did uses a driver trick. To use the same technique with DbContext you'd have to drop down to ADO.NET calls. `SqlQuery` doesn't allow specifying a command type

Comment: EF is not T-SQL, so it's reasonable to expect it may. As for what is actually sent to the database, it's `exec calendar.CropTime @d='2023-12-15 11:43:44'` (using the UDF from my example, it returns datetime). You can do that in T-SQL too: `declare @r datetime; exec @r = calendar.CropTime @d = '20230101 12:14:15'; select @r;`.