# How can I call a SQL function in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, function

I have created a function in SQL, now I need to use that function in my C# application.

I tried using something like this, but it seems I'm doing it wrong since I'm getting:

```
Must declare the scalar value '@2064734117'
```

...when I give `2064734117` as the first parameter and `1` as the second parameter. Here is the code I'm talking about:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(clsDb.connectionString);
string query = string.Format("select Function1(@{0},@{1}) ",
  int.Parse(e.CurrentRow.Cells["CodeMeli"].Value.ToString()),1);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
SqlDataAdapter READER = new SqlDataAdapter();
READER.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataTable table = new DataTable();
READER.Fill(table);
radGridView1.DataSource = table;
con.Close();
```

And my function takes two integer parameters and returns a table. I checked it in Visual Studio and it worked, but I couldn't get it to work in my application.

And this is my function declaration:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Function1
(
/*
@parameter1 int = 5,
@parameter2 datatype
*/
@ID int,
@clsTypeID int
)
    RETURNS TABLE/* @table_variable TABLE (column1 datatype, column2 datatype) */
    AS
         /*BEGIN */
    /* INSERT INTO @table_variable
       SELECT ... FROM ... */
RETURN SELECT  * FROM tblCLASS2 
        WHERE STNID = @ID AND CLASSTYPEID =  @clsTypeID  
/*END */
/*GO*/
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also one option is to write a stored procedure that calls your function and just call the proc via ado.net/c#

Comment: This code should work, what error is it giving? Note that this function does not *look like* a function, it would be better implemented in a `stored procedure`. However, it should work either way.

Comment: i get a "Must declare the scalar value '@2064734117'".  when i give 2064734117 as the first parameter and 1 as the second parameter.

Comment: Since it's a table valued function, shouldn't it be `select * from dbo.Function1(({0},{1})` rather than just `select dbo.Function1(({0},{1})` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your SQL is a bit off, it should be:

```
  string query = string.Format("select * from dbo.Function1({0},{1});", int.Parse(e.CurrentRow.Cells["CodeMeli"].Value.ToString()),1);
```

You might want to use SqlParameter-objects to prevent sql injections:

```
  string query = "select * from dbo.Function1(@pa1,@par2);";
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@par1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(e.CurrentRow.Cells["CodeMeli"].Value.ToString());  
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@par2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

At a glance, the first thing I can see is that you aren't specifying the object owner / schema; that is required for functions, so it should be `select dbo.Function1(...`

Second: look at what your call to `string.Format` generates; that is generating `@1` and `@n` for `n` another integer, but that **is not** a valid parameter name. Which is handy, because

Third: you didn't add any parameters

Fourth: for a table UDF (rather than a scalar UDF), you must `select * from dbo.Function1(...`, not just `select dbo.Function1(...`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
        myConn.Open();

        //generating the new command for our database
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT OBJECTID_1, NDNT as theAddress, MIN(ABS(x - " + double.Parse(x.ToString()) + ") + ABS(y - " + double.Parse(y.ToString()) +")) from dbo.DWH_OUTPUT  GROUP BY OBJECTID_1,NDNT HAVING   (MIN(ABS(x - " + double.Parse(x.ToString()) + ") + ABS(y - " + double.Parse(y.ToString()) + ")) = (Select MIN(ABS(a.x - " + double.Parse(x.ToString()) + ") + ABS(a.y - " + double.Parse(y.ToString()) + ")) from dbo.DWH_OUTPUT a ) )";
        cmd.Connection = myConn;

        //getting some more ado.net objects
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(ds, @"Addresses");

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            theAddress = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][@"theAddress"] + @" (proximity address)";
        }

        myConn.Close();
```

Note how in this example, you set the SqlCommand's CommandType to `CommandType.Text`.  Specify your command parameters (i.e. the select function in your code snippet), and then populate the dataset with the `Fill` method.  Then you can pluck out the values from the rows as you ordinarily would with standard ado.net.

If you need to call a stored proc, have a look at this:

[How do I call a TSQL function from ado.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145329/how-do-i-call-a-tsql-function-from-ado-net)

Answer (score 1):

You need fully qualified name of function with owner/schema name
[A working sample available at following link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056390/how-to-use-sql-user-defined-functions-in-net)